# Objective-c font names are different on different devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, fonts

I am trying to use a custom font called Hartland in my project. This font has two types: Hartland regular and Hartland bold.

On my iPhone 5s, the available font names are "HartlandRegular" and "HartlandLight"

But on my iPhone 4s the font names are "HartlandBold" and "HartlandRegular"

Even stranger, the font name "HartlandRegular" for one phone is the bold version on the other. To my knowledge I have successfully installed the fonts, but the names are inconsistent on different devices

Why are the fonts getting different names and how can I fix this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: it's not possible....Font is same for all devices..what issue actually you have ?

Comment: do you use custom font ?

Comment: This is the best article I've found on using custom fonts. Follow the steps to make sure that you've done everything correctly. It may help solve your problem. http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: the reason is the different architectures not the different versions of iOs.  The 64bit build accesses different ones from the 32bit build, so you might need some compile time switching

Answer (score -1):

I believe your issue actually has more to do with the latest iOS. You should be able to select the correct font using the interface builder - on older versions of xcode and iOS you used to have to set this with code.

Comment: True, but I need to be able to do it programatically